# How add php array with file_put_contents ? - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, file-put-contents

i want to add/create a php file with inside an array using `file_put_contents()`.

```
$arr= array('red');
$content= "<?php \n$".$var."=".$arr."\n?>"; 
file_put_contents('file.php', $content);
```

But then if i open `file.php` i read this:

```
 <?php
 $var=Array
 ?>
```

i would to see `array('red')`

I tried also `serialize()` but the output is bad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting an array to a string just returns `Array`. You can use [`var_export()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-export.php) to get an array literal to use there.

```
$content = "<?php \n\$" . $var . "=" . var_export($arr, true) . "\n?>";
```